# JavaScript callback node functionality

Tags: javascript

Please I am in need of help.

I can't understand how this code achieve its final output with input like 8, 7 and other values.

I know it is callback kind of a function but I don't understand behind the scenes the mathematical computation. I can't go forward if I can't overcome this code.

```
var fib = function(n) {
    if (n < 2) return n;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
};
```

Please I need in-depth explanation of the code in inner workings.

Comment: There's no callbacks involved there. I think the word you're looking for is "recursion".

Comment: I know what recursion is. I was just told it has to do with the Fibonacci sequence and I do understand the concept but I want to know how to apply it in the context of my code.

Comment: Try to use a pen and paper to "run" this function by hand for n = 3.

Comment: I have found the solution and it's very simple. It is all about Fibonacci Sequence Formula

Comment: @YusufMusa Well explain it then, for the next one :)